# Directional derivative in regression (coefficients, after all, are partial derivatives)

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, derivative, calculus

The coefficients in a (let's stick with linear for now) regression are the partial derivatives. A regression equation is a function of several variables, so all of the multivariable calculus tricks apply, yet I have never seen a directional derivative used explicitly.

What could be a case where a directional derivative would be used explicitly?

Comment: In what sense are regression coefficients partial derivatives, exactly?  (This reads like you are in search of a question to ask, rather than facing any statistical problem you need solved.)  Before you hasten to reply, contemplate models of the form $E[y]=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2z+\beta_3xz$ or even $E[y]=\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2x^2,$ both of which are common.